# a href link with basic authentication

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Basic Auth and Jquery and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)

I have a website were I login via basic authentication, that works fine. But when I want to download a .pdf file (that is generated by the server) I get a popup with the information that I need to login...again :/.

How can I prevent this? Or how can I send the basic authentication information with the link? I saw some examples, like: http://username:password@yourserver.com/filename.pdf . But that don't work in IE.

How can I solve this with only html and or jQuery?

edit:
I login via a form in the site, that works. But when I want to download an .pdf file while i'm logged in, I get the pop-up.

```
<a href="http://yourserver.com/yourpdffile.pdf">Report1.pdf</a>
```

Comment: What do you have server side? Issue shouldn't be solved on the client but (probably) on the server.

Comment: Even if it would work. Don't send passwords in the url.

Answer (score 3):

Basic authentication is Server based, HTML and jQuery are helpless here.

However, before sending AJAX request to such page, you can provide these details. Here is an example.

```
$.ajax({
    'url': 'http://yourdomain.com/action/',
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password) 
    },
    //.....
});
```

Comment: I'm not sending an ajax request when I retrieve the pdf. It's just a link and I need to authenticate again when I retrieve the pdf.

Comment: @AnnaSmother, If that link has HTTP authentication, then it will called automatically on navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the way you've written is possible (and should be supported by both, browser and server). But however, that's

1. A bad idea because of security (everyone could see the username and the password!) and
2. As you have written, it's not fully supported.

I don't know why it doesn't work in IE, but it's better not to use this.